# Zend Framework Service Manager not loading my model Class

Tags: model, zend-framework2

I am new at zend framework and having problem in fetching data from model. I am following its user guide but still not getting result here are my classes

name : Login.php

```
<?php
namespace Application\Model;

class Login
 {
// public $id;
 public $email;
 public $password;

 public function exchangeArray($data)
 {
     //$this->id     = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
     $this->email = (!empty($data['email'])) ? $data['email'] : null;
     $this->password  = (!empty($data['password'])) ? $data['password']     : null;
 }
 }

and finally module.php with all other functions including this

 // Add this method:
public function getServiceConfig(){
    print_r( array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Application\Model\LoginTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('ApplicationTableGateway');
                 $table = new LoginTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'ApplicationTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Login());
                 return new TableGateway('login', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
             },
         ),
    ));
}




LoginTable.php

namespace Application\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class LoginTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

 public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
 {
     $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
 }

 public function fetchAll()
 {
     $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
     return $resultSet;
 }
}

 This  code in module.php with its all default functions

 // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig(){
      return ( array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Application\Model\LoginTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('ApplicationTableGateway');
                 $table = new LoginTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'ApplicationTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Login());
                 return new TableGateway('login', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
             },
         ),
    )
}

 I have set up global.php and local.php before , Now i am calling this    from Controller

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
//
use Application\Model\Login;
use Application\Model\LoginTable;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

 class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $loginTable;

  public function getLoginTable()
 {
     if (!$this->loginTable) {
         $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();

            $this->loginTable = $sm->get('Application\Model\LoginTable');
     }
     return $this->loginTable;
 }


public function indexAction()
{

    $arr = array("id"=>"name");
    $this->getLoginTable()->fetchAll();


    return new ViewModel();
  }
}

My page getting blank???? Why Please help me , Its not giving any error?   If there is any other way to handle model classes then please help because at beginning level its hard to understand all code. Is there any other way that i can follow to create a single model class for each table.
```

If there is any tutorial link that explain it in better way then please mention it, All help will be appreciated,

Comment: Not sure if you just forgot for your question, however `print_r()` should be `return` in `getServiceConfig()`. You might also want to be a little more specific on your issues; what is 'not loading'? what results were you expecting?

Comment: I did print_r to just see the values in array. Here value is not getting set.

Comment: Yeah right. I am not be able to explain exactly whats the issue. Its little confusing for me too.